# Erro syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: php

Boa tarde galera, to com um problema nessa linha do código, alguém sabe porque?

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/storage/2/3e/eb/noticiasdasgerais/public_html/yteste/Controller/index.php on line 7

Trecho da linha 7:

```
public function indexAction() {

    if (isset($_POST['busca']) && !empty($_POST['busca'])) {
        $busca = addslashes($_POST['busca']);
        $this->autos = (new ModelAuto)->get_all_busca($busca); //Linha 7
    } else {

        $this->autos = (new ModelAuto)->get_autos_destaque();
    }
    $dados = $this->get_autos();
    Tpl::View("site/index", $dados);
}
```

Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Qual versão do php está usando?

Comment: A versão é 5.2.

Comment: Essa sintaxe só funciona do php5.4 para frente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nessa linha,

```
$this->autos = (new ModelAuto)->get_all_busca($busca);
```

Corrija dessa forma

```
$c = new ModelAuto;
$this->autos = $c->get_all_busca($busca);
```

Aliás, para evitar redundância, já que ambas as condições necessitam instanciar o mesmo objeto, ficaria assim:

```
public function indexAction() {

    $c = new ModelAuto;
    if (isset($_POST['busca']) && !empty($_POST['busca'])) {
        $busca = addslashes($_POST['busca']);
        $this->autos = $c->get_all_busca($busca); //Linha 7
    } else {

        $this->autos = $c->get_autos_destaque();
    }
    $dados = $this->get_autos();
    Tpl::View("site/index", $dados);
}
```

O motivo do erro é por estar usando uma versão anterior ao PHP5.4 no qual foi adicionado o recurso que permite acessar membros de uma classe durante a sua instanciação. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new
>   Foo)->bar().

Comment: Como eu faria então em uma função que acessa várias classes? Por exemplo:

public function get_autos() {
        $dados = array(
            'auto' => $this->autos['dados'],
            'paginacao' => $this->autos['paginacao'],
            'auto_recente' => (new ModelAuto)->get_autos_recente(),
            'auto_popular' => (new ModelAuto)->get_autos_popular(),
            'auto_topo' => (new ModelAuto)->get_autos_topo(),
            'slide' => (new ModelSlide)->getAll(1),
...

Comment: 'parceiro' => (new ModelSlide)->getAll(5),
            'servico' => (new ModelServico)->getAll(),
            'depoimento' => (new ModelDepoimento)->getAll(),
            'social' => (new ModelSocial)->getById(),
            'marca' => (new ModelMarca)->getAll(),
            'modelo' => (new ModelModelo)->getAll(),
            'agencia' => (new ModelAgencia)->getById(),
            'config' => (new ModelConfig)->getById()

Comment: leia a resposta...