# Erro syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Tags: php

Boa tarde galera, to com um problema com meu DB, mas não sei resolver, o erro é esse:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/storage/2/3e/eb/noticiasdasgerais/public_html/yteste/Lib/DB.php on line 44

A linha do código 44 é:

```
public function fetchAll($sql) {

        if ($this->pagination == true) {
            $res = $this->con->query($sql) or die($this->con->errorInfo()[2]); //tratamento de exceções  Linha 44
            $this->rows = count($res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
            $this->paginateLink();
            $sql .= " LIMIT $this->page, $this->perpage";
            $this->pagination = false;
        }
        $res = $this->con->query($sql) or die($this->con->errorInfo()[2]); //tratamento de exceções
        if ($res) {
            $this->data = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            return $this->data;
        }
    }
```

Alias a versão do php da minha hospedagem é 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É o mesmo problema dessa outra pergunta que você mesmo fez:

[Erro syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206566/erro-syntax-error-unexpected-t-object-operator)

Esse sistema que está tentando usar provavelmente foi escrito por alguém que não teve cuidado em manter uma retrocompatibilidade nos trechos onde utiliza recursos novos de versões mais recentes do PHP.

Esse recurso foi adicionado no PHP5.4: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].

Na versão 5.2 não é possível fazer esse tipo de acesso:

```
$this->con->errorInfo()[2]
```

Atribua o retorno do método a uma variável para então acessar o índice do array.

```
$error = $this->con->errorInfo();
echo $error[2];
```

Exemplo para o seu caso:

```
$res = $this->con->query($sql) or die($this->con->errorInfo()[2]);
```

Corrija assim:

```
if (!($res = $this->con->query($sql))) {
    $error = $this->con->errorInfo();
    die($error[2]);
}
```